React Native Expo notifications works with the Expo notification Tool but not device to device
My notifications works correctly with Expo Go and in Testflight when I send notifications with the Expo Notification Tool but not from a device to another.
This is my code to send notifications from a device :
const message = {
    to: expoPushToken,
    sound: 'default',
    title: body,
    body: '',
    data: { someData: 'goes here' },
  };

  await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      host: "exp.host",
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
  });

"react-native": "0.72.6",
"expo": "~49.0.15",
Thank you for your help !
I tried to use https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send to send notifications and i tried getDevicePushTokenAsync.
